# Is there any off the shelf system for renting and charging?

Tags: windows, web-apps

We would like to have bicycle rental service, due to that we need a system for charging. We just don't want to start from scratch to develop another system.

Basic requirements:

1. Record start & end renting time
2. Print out payment receipt
3. Distributed system, so that people rent at place A can return at place B.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Are you OK with both an online service, and maintaining your own server?

Comment: maintaining our own server would be better, thanks.

Comment: @MemoryLeak can you speak for ddd (you're in the same team, or that's also your account)?